# Using/setting up user authentication for sqlite3 in golang

Tags: sqlite, go, password-protection, go-sqlite3

I have to make my database password protected as a task in my school. For example if anyone tries to access my database it will ask the password.
I am trying to use **go-sqlite3** package and I have tried reading the official guide.
First step is to use `go build --tags <FEATURE>`.
It gaves me an error `build .: cannot find module for path .`
I dont know why and what are we building in the first place. I tried searching for practical examples also and didnt found any.
Can you explain to me how I can setup user authentication for my database using the golangs go-sqlite3 package?
[Link to the package](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3#user-authentication)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace `<FEATURE>` in that instruction by extension name(s) you want to enable from [table below](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3#feature--extension-list) (Seems there's an error in README and it has `sqlite_` prefix stripped in example; build [tag is indeed `sqlite_userauth`](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/671e666c2e88052a814eeaed6bc8506ef326eb63/sqlite3_opt_userauth.go#L6)).

So, to enable user authentication that will be `go build -tags "sqlite_userauth"`.

In your project with `go-sqlite3` module dependency just make sure that you build with `-tags sqlite_userauth`.

Here is minimal example showing how you would work with this in your project:

```sh
mkdir sqlite3auth
cd sqlite3auth
go mod init sqlite3auth
touch main.go
```

main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
        "database/sql"
        "log"

        "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
        // This is not necessary; just to see if auth extension is enabled
        sql.Register("sqlite3_log", &sqlite3.SQLiteDriver{
                ConnectHook: func(conn *sqlite3.SQLiteConn) error {
                        log.Printf("Auth enabled: %v\n", conn.AuthEnabled())
                        return nil
                },
        })

        // This is usual DB stuff (except with our sqlite3_log driver)
        db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3_log", "file:test.db?_auth&_auth_user=admin&_auth_pass=admin")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer db.Close()

        _, err = db.Exec(`select 1`)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

```sh
go mod tidy
go: finding module for package github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
go: found github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 in github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.14.10
# First build with auth extension (-o NAME is just to give binary a name)
go build -tags sqlite_userauth -o auth .
# then build without it
go build -o noauth .

./auth
2022/01/27 21:47:46 Auth enabled: true
./noauth
2022/01/27 21:47:46 Auth enabled: false
```

Comment: Why do I have to clone the repository? I am like modifying the repository and then installing thr modified repository to my project with go get? Cheers for helping :)

Comment: @KristoferKangro sorry it was hard to understand what you are trying to do; I modified my answer to show how you'd typically use go-sqlite3 in modules enabled project with user authentication extension enabled.

Comment: Cheers for nice answer! I am gonna look at it now and try to understand. I will get back if I have more issues

Comment: When I try to build with (as I did before posting) `go build -tags sqlite_userauth -o auth .` I get still the same error `build .: cannot find module for path . .` I am curious.. Based on what are we building?

Comment: @KristoferKangro the example above is fully working (unless you have very old version of  `go`). That error looks like `main` package of your project is not in same directory where you run `go build`. In that case you need to provide path to `main` package instead of `.` e.g. `go build cmd/foo` or so.

Comment: Never said yours is wrong. I am just trying to do it in my actual project. Okay, so go build uses main.go file to compile? Anyway it did not give me an error message so thats good! I will keep you updated

Comment: @KristoferKangro sorry didn't meant to accuse you of saying that. Just wanted to say that if you follow step-by-step you should get working build. `go build` takes path to a package (a directory of one or more `.go` files which have same `package <name>` header). To build binary this name has to be `main` and exactly one of them has to have `func main()`. It is all explained here https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241458/discussion-between-kristofer-kangro-and-blami).